# Kibana does not search on nested field

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

working with Elasticsearch/Kibana and trying to search on field in a nested object. However it does not seem to work. Here's mapping that I use in a template:

```js
{
  "order": 0,
  "template": "ss7_signaling*",
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "mapping.total_fields.limit": 3000,
      "number_of_shards": "5",
      "refresh_interval": "30s"
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "string_fields": {
            "mapping": {
              "fielddata": {
                "format": "disabled"
              },
              "index": "no",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "match": "*"
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "message": {
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Protocol": {
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "IMSI": {
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "nested": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        },
        "Timestamp": {
          "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
          "type": "date"
        },
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "@version": {
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "_all": {
        "norms": false,
        "enabled": false
      }
    }
  },
  "aliases": {
    "signaling": {}
  }
}
```

When I do search kibana on single fields - everything works fine. Still though i cannot search on nested fields like 'nested.name'.

Example of my query in kibana: nested.name:hi

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Kibana uses the `query_string` query underneath, and the latter [does not support querying on nested fields](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11322).

It's still being worked on but in the meantime you need to proceed differently.

**UPDATE**:

As of ES 7.6, it is now [possible to search on nested fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/release-highlights-7.6.0.html)