# Objects in arrays are not well supported

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using Kibana 6.5 and ES 6.5

I have an index blogcommentsinfo in ES database:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 5,
        "number_of_replicas": 1
    },
    "mappings":{
        "_doc":{
            "properties":{
                "post_id":{
                    "type":"long"
                },
                "comments_info":{
                    "type" : "nested",
                    "properties":{
                        "CommentTitle":{
                            "type":"text"
                        },
                        "CommentText":{
                            "type":"text"
                        },
                        "CommeVotes":{
                            "type":"short"
                        },                      
                        "CommentDate":{
                            "type":"date",
                            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I use Kibana -> Discover -> Table for index blogcommentsinfo, I get a notification next to comments_info:

> Objects in arrays are not well supported

Any why Kibana says this error? What is the guideline to use Kibana?

Comment: The reason is mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48398996/4604579